Error in keyword argument for matrix_rank
I want to compute the rank of a matrix, and introduce a certain relative tolerance to take into account the numerical errors. I use the following code :
    A = np.random.randn(n,n)
    r = np.linalg.matrix_rank(A, rtol = 1e-5)

but i get the following error : 'TypeError: matrix_rank() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rtol''
As written here : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_rank.html, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

What is your numpy version? You may check by pip list. This new feature seems to be added on 2.0.0

@RibomBalt My version is 1.26.4. I tried upgrading it but now it doesn't work with CVXPY, which I want to use aswell.

your version of NumPy does not support the rtol keyword in the np.linalg.matrix_rank so you can upgrade it or use this code
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randn(4, 4)
tol = 1e-5
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(A) 
rank = np.sum(s > tol * np.max(s)) 
print("Rank:", rank)

